# Do not display a "per page" select box, if products are not paginated

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pagination

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

The products are *12 per page by default*, but the user has the option to show 24 products per page.

Some (category) pages have less than 12 products, *therefore*, there is *no pagination*. I want, in such cases, the "per page" select box not to be displayed.

[image: Display "per page" select box only when there is pagination]

Adding a "paginated" class to the `<body>` tag would do the trick. How can I do *that*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try:

```
<?php if ($block->getLastPageNum() > 1): ?>
    <div class="field limiter form-inline pull-right">
        <label class="label" for="limiter">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Show') ?></span>
        </label>
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options form-control input-sm">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <span class="limiter-text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('per page') ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Are you getting the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

In `path/to/CustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml` I modified the line

```
<div class="field limiter form-inline pull-right">
```

to

```
<div class="field limiter form-inline pull-right <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()==1) { echo 'hidden'; } ?>">
```

The code above adds the "hidden" CSS class to the "limiter" if the products are not paginated:

```
<div class="field limiter form-inline pull-right hidden">
```