# Magento 2: How to add class "paginated" to the body tag if the products are paginated?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pagination

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I need to add class "paginated" to the body tag *if* the products category pages display pagination.

I have copied the `pager.phtml` file to  `app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/`, so that I can safely overwrite the defaults.

In this file, there is an if statement that "decides" when the pagination is displayed:

```
<?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
 // Pagination code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there anything I can add *inside this if statement* that would add class "paginated" to the body tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better solution to the problem this question is trying to solve: **[Do not display a “per page” select box, if products are not paginated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209272/do-not-display-a-per-page-select-box-if-products-are-not-paginated)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access of `block` class then you can do it like this,

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;

protected $pageConfig;


public function __construct(
    ...
    pageConfig $pageConfig
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
    ....
}
```

Now you can use this like,

```
$this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('test');
```

---

If you don't have access of `block` class then you can do it by `objectManager` (not recommended)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$pageConfig=$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');
$pageConfig->addBodyClass('test');
```

Comment: In *what file* shall I put this *second snippet* of code?

Comment: I have access to the entire project, but I do not know where the `block` class is. I am new to Magento.

Comment: For testing purpose you can put `objectManager ` code into <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
 // Pagination code here
 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: I have added it to `pager.phtml` file and it ruins it: the code appears in the browser.

Comment: appears in the browser means ?

Comment: I can see the code on the page as if it were content.

Comment: You need to add it under <?php ?> tags

Comment: I did this:
`<?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
 // Pagination code here
      <?php
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $pageConfig=$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');
            $pageConfig->addBodyClass('paginated');
        ?>
 <?php endif; ?>`. It does not add the class *paginated*.